# Inserting Aspose table after existing referenced table in Aspose document (.NET)

Tags: .net, insert, aspose

I have reference of existing table in Aspose word document by

```
(Table)wordDocument.GetChild(Note.Type.Table, 3, true)
```

I have newly created table. Is it possible to insert it after this referenced one?
In Aspose API I can find only to go to ParentNode and then to use InsertBefore, but I don't understand why it can't be used with referenced table?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to insert a new table after the referenced table.

```
// Load the document.
Document doc = new Document("Tables.docx");

// Get reference table in the document.
Table referenceTable = (Table)doc.GetChild(NodeType.Table, 1, true);

// Create a new table.
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
Table table = builder.StartTable();

// Insert a cell
builder.InsertCell();
builder.Write("This is row 1 cell 1");

// Insert a cell
builder.InsertCell();
builder.Write("This is row 1 cell 2");

builder.EndRow();

builder.EndTable();

// Insert the container after the original.
referenceTable.ParentNode.InsertAfter(table, referenceTable);

// Add a buffer paragraph to ensure the tables stay apart.
referenceTable.ParentNode.InsertAfter(new Paragraph(doc), referenceTable);

doc.Save("Tables_Out.docx");
```

I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.